# Make global "Logger" class available to every application class in php

Tags: php, oop

I have some classes that stores data to DB and I would like to implement a new `logger` class method to perform some logging operations after every pdo UPDATE statement.

Stated that

- every of these classes extends a `global` class
- I would like to have $logger class available into every class

I think I need to "include" a new `logger` class into the global one, is it right?

If yes, how should I do that in a correct `OOP` way? I need only some quick briefing, not detailed code...

Thank you

Comment: Going to need to see some actual code to help. But the traditional OOP way would be to create a decorator for your database class. This would require a clean OOP codebase that is already based around interfaces though.

Comment: What do actually mean by "global" class? "Global" as keyword or as an actual name? If you mean that the class should be accessible everywhere then just use some autoloading.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Global {

    private $logger = null; 

    protected function log($msg) {
      if ($this->logger === null) {
         $this->logger = new Logger();
      }
      $this->logger->log($msg);
   }
}
```

And in the other classes `$this->log('test')`

Edit:
A better way is to use dependency injection, with pimple for example.

Comment: How are you going to call `protected` methods from outside of the class?

Comment: I changed `protected` to `public` but get a `Class 'Logger' not found` error... should I set `global` to extend a new `Logger` class?

Comment: It is just an example. You need ja Logger which you create in the log function.

Comment: He has said all classes extend the global class.... so of course you can call a protected function